# Safari 8 not for windows?

Tags: safari, cross-browser, indexeddb, pouchdb

I'm trying to execute my program cross-browser and I found that Apple's Safari for windows ends with version 5.1.7! But when I searched all over the internet to acquire Safari 8, I found that they had no support for windows. I very badly want Safari 8 for windows since it has Indexeddb Support. And right now, the console at Safari5.1.7 shows me Invalid Adapter ERROR since my program uses IndexeddB! Any ideas for a workaround for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google found this for me:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/hh673548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Apparently, IE 10 has indexeddb support.

There is also indexeddb support in:

- Firefox (via an add-on) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/indexed-db
- Google Chrome - https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage

The obvious solution is to consign Safari on Windows to the same support category as IE5, IE6, Netscape, etcetera.  Stop supporting it.

(Seriously, you are not doing people a favour by helping them to limp along with ancient, probably EOL'd, and probably vulnerable browsers.  Anything you can do to encourage them to upgrade is a good thing.)

---

The best I could find for running IndexedDB on browsers that don't support it is this:

- https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim

No guarantees it is going to work for you ... or your users.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts :).  Guess I'll have to drop the idea of supporting Safari in my program as you suggest. It makes sense.

Comment: But wait, even if I wanted to support Safari, I must be using WebSQL in its place. Is it a good idea to use something that's deprecated?

Comment: @MassKent - It depends on how much you want to support old Safari browsers!  At some point, some browsers may cease to support WebSQL.  Then your app would have to have two different ways to IndexedDB. Do you want to have to do that?  If not, then that is another reason to not support older browsers ... like Safari for Windows.

Comment: You have to make a pragmatic decision here.  There is no good technological solution for dealing with old browsers in the long term.